# Как исправить ошибку “Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on array in” PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Решил обновить версию php с 5.3 на 7.0 начал писать код с помощью PDO, во время написания возникла ошибка:

**"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on array in /home/ecnlua/public_html/sitenew/php/pagination.php on line 12"**

Что-то связано с массивом. Если нужно избавится от **setResultToArray()**, то на что заменить?

```
<?php
    include_once("db.php");

    function getAllArticles($start, $limit) {
        $db = new Database;
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit);
        return setResultToArray($result);
    }

    function setResultToArray($result) {
        $array = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetchAll()){
            $array[] = $row;
        }
//      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $array[] = $row;
        return $array;
    }

    function countArticles() {
        $db = new Database();
        $reslut = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `news`");
        $result = mysql_fetch_row($reslut);
        return $result[0];
    }

    function getStart($page, $limit) {
        return $limit * ($page - 1);
    }

    function pagination($page, $limit) {
        // общее кол-во строк в БД
        $count_articles = countArticles();
        // общее количество стр.
        $count_pages = ceil($count_articles / $limit);
        if ($page > $count_pages) $page = $count_pages;
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        if ($prev < 1) $prev = 1;
        if ($next > $count_pages) $next = $count_pages;
        $pagination = "";
        if ($count_pages > 1) {
            // pagination
            if ($page == 1) {
                $pagination .= "<span>1Первая </span>";
                $pagination .= "<span>1Предыдущая </span>";
            }
            else {
                $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'>2Первая </a>";
                if ($prev == 1) $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'>2Предыдущая </a>";
                else $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$prev."'>21Предыдущая </a>";
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count_pages; $i++) {
                if ($i == $page) $pagination .= "<span> ".$i." </span>";
                elseif ($i == 1) $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'> ".$i." </a>";
                else $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i." </a>";
            }
            if ($page == $count_pages) {
                $pagination .= "<span> 3Следующая</span>";
                $pagination .= "<span> 3Последняя</span>";
            }
            else {
                $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$next."'> 4Следующая</a>";
                $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$count_pages."'> 4Последняя</a>";
            }
        }
        return $pagination;
    }

?>
```

Comment: `db->query()` у вас уже похоже возвращает массив.

Comment: @teran супер заработало вообще убрал `function setResultToArray($result)`. Ещё вопрос как можно заменить `$result = mysql_fetch_row($result); ругается на него

Comment: опять таки, если у вас `db->query` возвращает массив, то просто убираете строку с `fetch_row`, она вам не нужна вовсе. а далее возвращаете что-то вроде `return $result ? current($result) : null;` хотя там будет целая строка, а вам надо первый элемент. Расширьте свой класс `db` какими-нибудь удобными методами кроме `query`. Да и в целом, лучше все же отделить метод `query` от создания массива результата.

Comment: @teran Супер, спасибо друг!